# Need to figure it out why the code is no reading the data from the file and giving me the wrong answer

Tags: c++

I need help understanding what I'm doing wrong in my coding(c++). The program should then display the number of times that team has won the World Series whenever I put a team name on the output. Instead, I keep getting: New York Yankees has won the World Series 0 times.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <stream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
//variables
string teams, winners;
string TeamsList[200] = {};
string WinnersList[200] = {};

int counter = 0;

//open file Teams
ifstream teamsFile;
teamsFile.open("Teams.txt");

//If it does not open display "error"
if(!teamsFile){
    cout << "error" << endl;
    return 0;
}
// If it does open display the content of the file
cout << "Team won World Series: \n";
while (getline(teamsFile, teams)){
    cout << teams << endl;
}
//close file
teamsFile.close();

//ask for a input
cout << "Enter team name to see if win World Series: \n";
getline(cin, teams);

bool found = false;

// Search for the input
for (int i = 0; i < winners.size(); i++){
    if(TeamsList[i] == teams){
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
//open the winners file
ifstream winnersFile;


winnersFile.open(WorldSeriesWinners.txt");

// If it does not open display "error"
if(!winnersFile){
    cout << "error" << endl;
    return 0;
}
// If it does open count the number of times that the team won
while(getline(winnersFile, winners)){
    if(winners == winners)
        counter++;
}
//display result
cout << teams << " has won the world series " << counter << " times. 
 \n ";

winnersFile.close();

return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Now would be a great time to run this in a debugger and step through the code to ensure it is doing what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there's a problem with your input when you obtain the name of the team here

```
cout << "\n Enter Team Name to verify it's World Series Wins: \n";
getline(cin, name);
```

If this `name` contains whitespace characters, it won't match with the team name obtained via the `winner` string here

```
while(getline(inputFile, winner)){
```

e.g. Entering `New York Yankees`  (with a space at the end) won't match the string `winner` (or the problem could be the other way round that the `Winners.txt` has a space or something else around the team name). Use a debugger and to help determine why there's a problem you could use some diagnostic like:

```
std::cout<<"Got winner ["<<winner<<"]\n";
if(winner == name) {
    counter++;
    std::cout<<'['<<winner<<"] matches with ["<<name<<"]\n";
}
```

To help figure out if the input `name` actually matches with the read-in `winner` and is without any extra character.

Another thing is that, for the particular problem (and way of solving), you don't really need to read in the `Teams.txt` since you can just compare the read-in `winner` from the `Winners.txt` and compare it with the input `name` unless of course, one needs to validate whether the input `name` is actually a valid team-name before even starting to compare it with the names in `Winner.txt`
Also, there's a bug in your program (which won't show up for the current use) here:

```
while(getline(inputFile, winner)){
    Winners[Winner++] = name;
```

This should be instead

```
Winners[Winner++] = winner;
```

to store the actual `winner` read in from the file rather than the `name` read in from user input.

Comment: Your help was, very useful. But, now whenever I put a name on the team, the answer is that they have won 116 times. This happens for all the teams that I put in. I'm new in programming and I'm VERY confused. Would you please help me or explain to me what I'm doing wrong

Comment: @Karla Could you share what does your new code look like? Also, do go through [this](https://www.cprogramming.com/gdb.html) link and use [this](https://www.onlinegdb.com/) site to debug your program. Take your time but learning debugging is really essential to fixing programs.

Comment: I just edited my code, you can see that the code is slightly changed from the last one.

Comment: @Karla You have the line `if(winners == winners)` in your code. This will always be true and basically the value of `counters` at the end will be the total number of entries in `WorldSeriesWinners.txt`. I think you need to change that to `if(teams == winners)`. Also you are never storing anything in `TeamList` array. I'm not sure what is its purpose.